# Selenium webdriver.Remote gets SSL errors on Linux, works on macOS

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, ssl, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to scrape a third party site using Selenium (I tried using Beautiful Soup, but their authentication system is too difficult to understand so I bailed and used Selenium instead).

I'm using a python script that uses the latest Selenium 3.12.0 drivers, and the `selenium-server-standalone-3.12.0.jar`. Both my Linux and macOS boxes are running jdk 1.8.0_172.

If I run the script on either Linux or macOS with the selenium server on macOS it works great. If I run the script on either Linux or macOS with the selenium server on Linux, it fails to load jQuery with the following error:

```
18:28:02.453 ERROR [DefaultJavaScriptErrorListener.loadScriptError] - Error loading JavaScript from [https://ww6.fltplan.com/js/jquery-1.12.3.min.js].
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
   at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1002)
   at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1385)
```

The site I'm scraping is written very primitively (looks like something out of GeoCities) so it's very likely it's doing something absurd. Oh, and this code was working a few weeks ago and I "froze" it, but then it stopped working in Linux and I had to start tinkering with it again.

Here's my connect code:

```
capabilities = {
        'browserName': 'htmlunit',
        'version': 'firefox',
        'platform': 'ANY',
        'javascriptEnabled': True,
        'acceptInsecureCerts': True,
}
driver = webdriver.Remote(
    # "http://192.168.1.46:4444/wd/hub", webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.HTMLUNITWITHJS
    # "http://localhost:4444/wd/hub", webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.HTMLUNITWITHJS
    "http://localhost:4444/wd/hub", capabilities
)

driver.get("https://www.fltplan.com/")
```

The first commented out Remote url is to Selenium running on my macOS box, it works. The second and third are attempts to make it work on Linux, so far unsuccessful. The second one is the one that worked up until a few weeks ago.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have a solution. I make a copy of the java.security file in `java_home/jre/lib/security` and commented out all the "disabledAlgorithms" lines in the file. I start up the selenium server with `nohup java -Djava.security.properties==java.security.copy -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.12.0.jar` and it seems to work now.

I'd be interested in hearing an explanation why this works. I assume it means the site they're trying to download jquery from uses encryption that jdk 1.8 disables because it's considered too weak.